# Kivy mapview - Place button widgets ontop of mapview widget

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to add some widgets to a Kivy mapview like this

```
mapview = self.mapWidget(self.lat, self.lon)        
touchBarbtn1 = Button(text='Unlock')
touchBarbtn1.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.centerOnUser())
mapview.add_widget(touchBarbtn1)
```

But no matter what layout options I give it, it's always stuck in the bottom left corner. Even if I add more widgets they all just stack on top of each other in the bottom left corner. My Goal is to make a button on the top right corner to center the map on the user.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [Kivy Anchor Layout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html).
2. If you are going to add more buttons, my suggestion is to use [Kivy Drop-Down List](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html).

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class RootWidget(AnchorLayout):
    lat = NumericProperty(50.6394)
    lon = NumericProperty(3.057)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.anchor_x = 'right'
        self.anchor_y = 'top'
        mapview = MapView(zoom=11, lat=self.lat, lon=self.lon)
        self.add_widget(mapview)
        touchBarbtn1 = Button(text='Unlock', size_hint=(0.1, 0.1))
        touchBarbtn1.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.centerOnUser())
        self.add_widget(touchBarbtn1)

    def centerOnUser(self):
        pass


class MapViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


MapViewApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Unlock Button Top Right Corner]

Comment: You are welcome. Please remember to mark your question as answered by *Clicking the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".* Thank you.