# Kivy Scatter z-index

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am trying to make an kivy app for simulating simple ecosystem, with kind of interactive map, which can be zoomed and positioned by dragging by user. My first approach to achieve this was using Kivy Scatter widget, which seems to satisfy these requirements. Here's my code (to keep it simple, just gui with buttons and map on the right, with big red rectangle):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color

class GUI(BoxLayout):

    board = ObjectProperty(None)

    def draw(self):
        with self.board.canvas:
            Color(1,0,0)
            Rectangle(pos=(0,0),size=(300,300))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        gui = GUI()
        gui.draw()
        return gui

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = TestApp()
    app.run()
```

and my .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9


<GUI>:
    board: scatter_board
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    spacing: 30
    padding: 30
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 0.25, 1
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Start/Resume'
        Button:
            text: 'Stop'
    Scatter:
        id: scatter_board
        size_hint: 0.75,1
```

However, in this situation, while user drags the map over the button, it is not possible anymore to click it (it doesn't get highlighted on click). I tried:

- setting scatter's 'auto_bring_to_front' to False
- using 'index' property of both scatter and buttons' parent BoxLayout to manipulate z-index.

So basically I want the 'map' not to shadow the button, but to stay below it. Is it possible to achieve this effect with Scatter? Or is it a wrong use-case of scatter, and I should change the approach? If so, do you know any similar and possibly simple ways?

Comment: Please check out this post which place buttons / dropdown list on top of a mapview with scatter widget [Kivy MapView - Place button widgets ontop of mapview widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800345/kivy-mapview-place-button-widgets-ontop-of-mapview-widget)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem.
After reading the answer above I found you need to put the Scatter in a boxlayout of its own. And NOT use a ScatterLayout, like i was doing initially, because then it won't do what you want (go under the buttons in stead of over them).

I did it like this:

```
# Creating Scatter Class 
class TreeWidget(Scatter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #self.auto_bring_to_front = False
        ...

class ShowApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        treeBox = BoxLayout()
        self.treeWidget = TreeWidget()
        treeBox.add_widget(self.treeWidget)

        buttonFile = Button(text='File', size_hint=(None, None), size=(60, 30))
        buttonFile.bind(on_press=self.chooseFile)
        buttonSave = Button(text='Save', size_hint=(None, None), size=(60, 30))
        buttonSave.bind(on_press=self.saveFile)
        buttonBox = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        buttonBox.add_widget(buttonFile)
        buttonBox.add_widget(buttonSave)
    
        boxLayout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        boxLayout.add_widget(treeBox)
        boxLayout.add_widget(buttonBox)
        return boxLayout
```